Why is the VS Code terminal adding indents to blocks when I run them?
Fairly new to python and don't have much formal programming knowledge so hopefully one of you can help.
I previously used VSCode to run python scripts and it worked fine, but after some updates I'm having issues. When I run a block of code (defining a function, for loop, while loop, ect.) the terminal adds one indent to every line after the first, and keeps that indentation from one block to the next. I can run the code in the debugger just fine, but I don't know how to tell what's different between the two and havent found anything online of anyone with a similar issue.
If there is any additional info that would be helpful for troubleshooting or understanding this, please let me know. I don't know what would or wouldn't be useful.
I tried running a for loop with only one indented line and it worked as expected:
>>> for i in range(0,2):
...         print(i)
... 
0
1

But if I add a second line to the loop with the same indentation in the editor and run it, the terminal adds an additional indent to that second line then throws an indentation error:
What I typed in the editor:
for i in range (0,2):
    print(i)
    print("test")

What shows up in the terminal by highlighting and using shift+enter:
>>> for i in range (0,2):
...             print(i)
...                 print("test")
... 
  File "<python-input-1>", line 3
    print("test")
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> 

Interestingly, if I run that same line again, the two print statements are each indented an additional time and the same error occurs:
>>> for i in range (0,2):
...                 print(i)
...                     print("test")
... 
  File "<python-input-2>", line 3
    print("test")
IndentationError: unexpected indent


This seems to be a recently introduced bug, that is reported and addressed already. Can't find the link at moment though.

dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/79118499/11107541. cc @KlausD.

you seem to be having more than 4 spaces for your indentation in the command you ran, that's why you have an indentation error. An indentation in python is 4 spaces.
Don't mix spaces and tabs when you want to indent, use one or the other and not both. Hopefully that helps.
