VS Code adds unwanted indents when running in terminal
I'm new to VS Code and Python and apologize if this is a basic question.
I wrote this function in VS Code using four spaces for each indent...
def is_strong_password(password):
    if len(password) < 8:
        return False
    if password.islower():
        return False
    if password.isupper():
        return False
    if password.isnumeric():
        return False
    return True

And the only extension I'm running is Python.
When I select all of it and press shift-enter (or run selection/line in python terminal), why do I get this error?
PS C:\Users\DaveLewandowski\Documents\learn_with_copilot> & C:/Users/DaveLewandowski/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/python.exe
Python 3.13.1 (tags/v3.13.1:0671451, Dec  3 2024, 19:06:28) [MSC v.1942 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def is_strong_password(password):
...         if len(password) < 8:
...                         return False
...                             if password.islower():
...                                             return False
...                                                 if password.isupper():
...                                                                 return False
...                                                                     if password.isnumeric():
...                                                                                     return False
...                                                                                         return True
... 
  File "<python-input-0>", line 4
    if password.islower():
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> 


Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79118499/visual-studio-code-does-not-print-to-terminal-with-correct-indentation (try with python 3.12)
